# Which projection is more suitable?

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography

I need to make a map using equidistant cylindrical projection with normal
orientation. But I'm getting confused - I've tried 2 projections -

```
WGS_1984_Plate_Carree
WKID: 32662 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Plate_Carree
False_Easting: 0,0
False_Northing: 0,0
Central_Meridian: 0,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)
```

And

```
 World_Equidistant_Cylindrical
WKID: 54002 Authority: ESRI

Projection: Equidistant_Cylindrical
False_Easting: 0,0
False_Northing: 0,0
Central_Meridian: 0,0
Standard_Parallel_1: 60,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)
```

Both look completely different. Is that because of "standard parallel", which 2nd projection has? Is 1st projection the right one or should I use something else?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I think folks object because you ask which is "more suitable" without giving a purpose. Maybe you wish to ask "why are they different"? (The answer *is* because of the different standard parallels.)

Answer (score 2):

EPSG:32662 has the latitude of true scale at the equator, while EPSG:54002 has it at 60° North/South. You have a distortion with both, so it is up to your personal taste to choose. See http://proj4.org/projections/eqc.html for some choices.

A projection like Robinson surely approximates the reality better than any Equidistant Cylindrical can.